# Cannot get K prompt on Timex 1500

Tags: video

I started tinkering with a Timex Sinclair 1500 I was given awhile ago. When I first tried starting it, I got a K prompt in the lower left of the screen. I turned it off and did not return to it for a few weeks. Now, I do not see a K prompt when I try turning it on and even restarting it. Sometimes there are wide black vertical bars on the screen or small black squares in patterns. Has this machine died? I am using an old black and white portable analog TV with a dial for precisely tuning channels like 2 and 3.

Comment: Certainly you should see the K without further ado; can you elaborate on the black squares? Also does anything change if you type?

Comment: A photo of the black squares would help us work out what's wrong

Comment: I know from fiddling around with a ZX81 that I sometimes only get a K on about the tenth attempt to connect it to the power source. Also any peripherals attached can make the job much harder.

Comment: Until we have photographs or more details, this is too broad to answer; there are many possible things that could result in this situation.